# Объявление функции в библиотеке, реализация в исполняемом проекте, как их связать?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компоновщик

Есть библиотека с заголовком App.h

```
namespace Test 
{
 int AppStart();
}
```

И cpp файлом main.cpp

```
#include "App.h"
extern int Test::AppStart();
int main() {
    return Test::AppStart();
}
```

В другом исполняемом проекте файл App.cpp

```
#include <App.h>
#include <iostream>
int Test::AppStart() 
{
    std::cout << "App Start" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка: `main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl Test::AppStart(void)" (?AppStart@Test@@YAHXZ) в функции main`

Comment: А прошла ли успешно *компиляция* `app.cpp`? у вас в нем `#include <App.h>` с угловыми скобками... Потому что как только я это изменил, у меня все нормально скомпилировалось и собралось...

Comment: App.cpp должно быть в библиотеке, а main.cpp - в исполняемом проекте. В `App.h` должны быть include guards. А вот `extern int Test::AppStart();` быть не должно.

Comment: @Harry, через кавычки тоже не помогает, файл App.obj есть. Я подключал библиотеку через ссылки в vs studio, и добавил каталоги включения в свойствах проекта. Может что не так сделал?

Comment: @user7860670, в этом и суть. Мне нужно чтобы main был в библиотеке, она отвечала за запуск цикла программы.  Это можно сделать, я уже делала только не помню как.

Comment: Ну, еще вариант — в файле реализации создайте namespace Test — как в заголовочном — и реализуйте AppStart() внутри пространства имен, а не просто с полностью квалифицированным именем. Что-то такое у меня когда-то на VC++ (кстати, у вас какая версия?) было, такое решение работало. Проверьте... Кстати, кажется, это было, когда оформлял такие вещи в библиотеку — с классами вроде проходило нормально, а вот свободные функции пришлось заворачивать в пространства имен.

Comment: Harry, пространства имен добавил, тоже не помогло. версия 199711 (с++98 как я понимаю). Я собираю в dll.  Можете скинуть свой проект, может я в свойствах не правильно указал что указал?

Comment: Я в командной строке компилировал :) Кстати, а что получается, ели в командной строке запустить `cl /EHsc main.cpp app.cpp`? Еще версия — что при линковке `app.obj` он просто не видит, он как-то не так добавлен...

Comment: @Harry, файлы main.cpp и app.cpp в разных проектах, в разных папках, если указать полный путь к файлам, он не может найти app.h

Comment: Похоже, он у вас из-за этого (или чего еще) не в состоянии найти объектный файл.